# get duration in seconds grouped by ID column in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I want to calculate duration of a column in seconds grouped by IP and the column for an ip looks like below:
EventTimeStamp  ip  Browser BrowserVersion  Deviceos    GeoCarrier  GeoCity GeoCountry  GeoRegion   PageExperience  PageName    PageParentUrl   PageType    PageUrl

```
TimeStamp           ID
2022-02-09 18:23:01 101 
2022-02-09 18:23:02 101 
2022-02-09 18:23:03 101
2022-02-09 18:23:03 101
2022-02-09 18:23:03 101
2022-02-09 18:23:07 101 
2022-02-09 18:23:08 101 
2022-02-09 18:23:21 101 
2022-02-09 18:23:21 101
```

For this ID, the duration should be calculated as 20 seconds.
and if there is only one entry for an ID, duration should be zero.

I tried below code, but it gives me

```
p=df[df['ID']=='101']
p['TimeStamp'].tail(1)-p['TimeStamp'].head(1)

0   NaT
8   NaT
Name: TimeStamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Datatype of the columns are:

```
df.dtypes
    
    TimeStamp     datetime64[ns]
    ID                    object
```

and this piece of code to get duration of each ID:
duration = []

```
for ip,tempdf in df.sort_values(['ID','TimeStamp']).groupby('ID'):
    d = ((tempdf['TimeStamp'].tail(1)-tempdf['TimeStamp'].head(1)))
    duration.append(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below command helped me to solve my problem.
This query gives duration in seconds for each ID.

```
duration = []
for ID,tempdf in df.groupby('ID'):
    tail = (tempdf['TimeStamp'].sort_index().iloc[-1])
    head = (tempdf['TimeStamp'].sort_index().iloc[0])
    diff = (tail-head).seconds
    duration.append(diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` with `np.ptp`:

```
 df.groupby('ID')['TimeStamp'].apply(np.ptp).dt.total_seconds()
```